# breakpoints isn't hit after hot reloading in nuxt3

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, nuxtjs3

I attach chrome browser in vscode and modify vue file. After modifying the source code, the hot reload is working, but the breakpoints are not being hit. When checking the devtool, it seems that a file named "..blahblah..vue?t=1649302311122" is being added, and this might be a hint to the issue.